# Unidirectional @OneToOne with reversed foreign key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

We'd like to create unidirectional `@OneToOne` mapping with foreign key that is not in the master table, but in the slave. By providing following java code, Hibernate tries to find column `product_ID` in the table `product` but not in `productimage`. Is it possible to make it working with the only modifications to annotations?

All unnecessary fields and columns have been stripped from the example.

JPA entities:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
    private String id;

    // this doesn't work
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_ID", nullable = false)
    private ProductImage productImage;

    // this works, but we want one-to-one
    // @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    // @JoinColumn(name = "product_ID", nullable = false)
    // private List<ProductImage> productImages;

    // getters/setters omitted
}

@Entity
public class ProductImage {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
    private String id;

    @Column
    @Lob
    private Blob data;

    // getters/setters omitted
}
```

Database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)

CREATE TABLE `productimage` (
  `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `data` longblob NOT NULL,
  `product_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_123` (`product_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_123` FOREIGN KEY (`product_ID`) REFERENCES `product` (`ID`)
)
```

Comment: Read jpa documentation for @JoinColumn. For OneToOne you should use referencedColumnName in your use case. From performance point of view, you should consider placing reference to product table

Comment: After a set of modification to annotations you end up with invalid schema definition.

Comment: Sometimes you need to question why a database schema is the way it is. Why does `productimage` reference `product`, instead of `product` referencing `productimage`? If you really want the schema this way, why not define the association in `ProductImage` back to `Product` and then use a `mappedBy` association in `Product`?

Comment: @DuncanKinnear, The schema is prepared for a possible future case where product will be able to have multiple images. Then we will only change the annotation to `@OneToMany` and use `List<ProductImage>` instead of the single `Product` reference. We don't want to reference `Product` from `ProductImage` unles really necessary.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen, I've tried `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "product_ID", nullable = false) private ProductImage productImage;` but then I got the exception `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: product_ID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(ProductImage) and its related supertables and secondary tables`.

Comment: @Martin Can you explain why you don't want to reference `Product` from `ProductImage`? That is the most logical way to do this, especially if you might change this to be a `@OneToMany` later on. That way the association in `Product` can use `mappedBy` for either a `@OneToOne` or a `@OneToMany`. If you are saying that a `ProductImage` _belongs_ to a `Product`, then it is natural to have a reference from `ProductImage` to the `Product` that _owns_ it.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear, there is no place in our code where we would directly benefit from referencing `Product` from `ProductImage`, it would be just to satisfy JPA. The same will be true once we'll have `List` of `ProductImage`s in `Product`. Also `@OneToMany` can already be done unidirectionally, in my example just by uncommenting the commented block. We are using this approach in other places of our code already. For example see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2096971/289827.

Comment: @Martin Yes, but your argument could be just as easily applied to a foreign key in the database. If you don't use it, why have it? Because it benefits the _structure_ of your application. In this case, it is explicitly there to make your JPA structure a lot easier. Don't fight it just because _you_ think it is bad.

Answer (score 2):

@OneToOne is a little misleading. It is most likely different from what you want. Classic database "one to one" relationship is modeled via @ManyToOne JPA annotation in most cases. Try it. Never had a problem with uni-directional relationships via @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn. I'd also explicitly specify productId field in the second class.

Comment: Thanks. If I have specified `product` reference in `ProductImage` then it would work, but the relation would be bidirectional. Also, maybe you meant `@OneToMany` in `Product` class. With `@ManyToOne` I wasn't successful.

Comment: Yes. Looks like it is a good approach. But we have to have a unique constraint on the FK column (if we use it in place of a primary key joining).

Answer (score 2):

JPA entities, more on [`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html):

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @OneToOne(orhanRemoval = true)
    private ProductImage image;
}

@Entity
public class ProductImage {
    @Id
    private String productId; // this will be foreign key as well as primary

   //other properties goes here
}
```

Database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE product_image (
    product_id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES product(id)
    -- other columns goes here
);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question. Also, this answer assumes that the `Product` and `ProductImage` share the same primary key - without explaining it - which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you map it as @OneToOne or @OneToMany is really neither here nor there: clients can only use what you expose so Map it as @OneToMany and hide the implementation.

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true)
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_ID", nullable = false)
    private List<ProductImage> productImages;

    //no getters or setters for productImages;

    public ProductImage getProductImage(){
         return productImages.size() > 0 ? productImages.get(0) : null;
    }
}
```

I also do not see any particular issue with making the relationship bidirectional either as 1-2-1 or 1-2-M. Again, don't expose the reference from ProductImage > Product if you don't want it publicly available.

Comment: "map it as @OneToMany and hide the implementation" - that's my current workaround :-). With `@OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "product_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false) private ProductImage productImage;` I still get the error `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: product_ID in acme.product`.

Comment: I do not see any practical difference between 1-2-1 or 1-2-m in terms of db access so why not just go with that then or make it a bidirectional 1-2-1. As I say, no client code needs be aware of how this implemented.